# Long tomcat start up time for spring application

Tags: spring, tomcat

I am running the following:

- tomcat 7 / java 1.7 / mysql / ejabbered xmpp
- spring 3.2 - spring core, mvc, security, jdbc

I have recently observed that the tomcat server takes upto 11 mins to startup and I would want to troubleshoot the issue. There isnt much for me to go ahead with and hence seeking help.

Running spring under DEBUG mode, I get the following:

```
Jul 06 17:02:17 INFO  onSecurityMetadataSourceParser ilterInvocationRequestMap Creating access control expression attribute 'hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SYSTEM_ADMIN')' for /**
Jul 06 17:13:37 INFO  tpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder     Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1800, <blacklistFilter>, order = 1899, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 1900, <projectRolesConfiguratorFilter>, order = 1901, <termsConditionsCheckerFilter>, order = 2147483646]
```

You can see that there is a 11 min gap between the two lines.. 
Not sure what is spring doing between this time. There definitely isnt anything worth loading for so long.

Any ideas pls ?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you try restarting tomcat? Tomcat is notorious for leaking memory and if it is exceeding your memory it would go to your swap which is exponentially slower than memory.  I don't see anything in your logs that would cause it to be slow.

Comment: See your code for blacklistFilter , projectRolesConfiguratorFilter, termsConditionsCheckerFilter .One of these may have slow initialization.

Comment: Thank you, something doesnt seem right. I verified the version control logs and these filter code have been there since ever and there has been no changes recently. So, definitely nothing to do with the code. Very (very) strangely, I did observe that repeated restarts do reduce the startup time from 11 mins to 7, 5 and now 3 mins ... but these just doesnt make any rational sense... Tomcat gets stuck at the same location in log every time.  Is there any way, I can increase the logs in tomcat to see what is it doing ? Use any other tool e.g. jvisualvm might help ?